# Cannot call method 'addMethod' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Getting "cannot call method 'addMethod' of undefined" when browser executes the below line fo code.

```
$.validator.addMethod("regex", function (value, element, param){
    return this.optional(element) || param.test(value);
});
```

Comment: Seems like the validatorplugin is not loaded or in the wrong script order...

Comment: I am using jquery.validate/1.10.0. do you have any idea which script order has to be corrected ?

Comment: Got the issues fixed. The issue is the same JS files is being rendered from multiple sources caused that issues.

Comment: The plugin just needs to be listed before the file or codeblock which contains your samplecode...

Answer (score 2):

That means that there is no `$.validator` and your try to call a method of a `null`. You're probably missing an import of a plugin which defines `$.validator`.